# xQuery - multiple nodes

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery-sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT     
CAST(spi.dbo.UserInfo.XmlContent AS xml).value('(/UserInfo[1]/@SystemId)','VARCHAR(32)') as SystemId,
CAST(spi.dbo.UserInfo.XmlContent AS xml).value('(/UserInfo[1]/@LoginId)','VARCHAR(32)') as LoginId,
--CAST(spi.dbo.UserInfo.XmlContent AS xml).value('(/UserInfo[1]/ChangeInfo/@UserId)[3]','VARCHAR(32)')AS SystemID
CAST(spi.dbo.UserInfo.XmlContent AS xml).value('count(/UserInfo/ChangeInfo)', 'INT') AS 'Count'
FROM UserInfo
WHERE CAST(spi.dbo.UserInfo.XmlContent AS xml).value('(/UserInfo[1]/ChangeInfo)[1]','VARCHAR(32)') = 'John'
```

The issue I am having is that the node `ChangeInfo` can be in multiples in some XML records.

How can I search all nodes rather than having to be explicit and naming the count of a node, say `ChangeInfo[1]`?

Comment: Why do you need to cast this `XmlContent`? This should be a native XML type column...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to cast the column `XmlContent`? This should be a native XML type column... This cast is very expensive and keeping XML in a non-XML column is very erronous...

Without showing your XML this is *flying blind-folded*, but my magic crystal ball told me, that you might be looking for something like this:

```
SELECT     
    A.CastedToXml.value('(/UserInfo/@SystemId)[1]','VARCHAR(32)') as SystemId,
    A.CastedToXml.value('(/UserInfo/@LoginId)[1]','VARCHAR(32)') as LoginId,
    B.ci.value('(/UserInfo/ChangeInfo/@UserId)[1]','VARCHAR(32)') AS ChangeInfo_UserID,
    A.CastedToXml.value('count(/UserInfo/ChangeInfo)', 'INT') AS ChangeInfo_Count
FROM spi.dbo.UserInfo ui
OUTER APPLY(SELECT CAST(ui.XmlContent AS xml)) A(CastedToXml)
OUTER APPLY A.CastedToXml.nodes('/UserInfo/ChangeInfo') B(ci)
WHERE CastedToXml.exist('/UserInfo/ChangeInfo[text()="John"]')=1;
```

I use an `APPLY` to add the *xml-casted* column to the result-set. The second `APPLY` will return all nested `<ChangeInfo>` elements as a derived table.

The `WHERE`-clause uses the XML method `.exist()`. This will check for any occurance of the given `Xpath` anywhere in the XML. If needed you can introduce the literal "John" with `sql:variable()` or `sql:column` from outside dynamically.

One hint: Try to learn about table aliases and how to avoid repeated code.